# Creating "multiple layer selection" with Qt Designer

Tags: qgis, qt-designer

I want to create a multiple selection box (like you can see when you click on the processing saga tool "Merge vector layers") with the Qt Designer.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your question is very broad, can you narrow the focus?  What specific aspect do you need help with?  What have you tried?

Comment: I'm writing my 1st python script. The thing is that I have more than one vector layer to select (for further data processing). I was able to create a selecting box (just for one layer) on the Qt designer. Now I trying to find a way to create (or maybe coding with python) a multi selection box like you can see in the screenshot.

Answer (score 3):

In QT you may use the QList Widget.  There are various selection options under selectionMode setting you may pick from to enable mutli text selection, see graphic below:

[image]

For selecting features or all features in a layer you first need to create QGIS Vector layer that references the layer on disk or in a database, and then perform the selection query.  There are many posts on this site and others (search for pyqgis create vector layer, pyqgis select layer or select feature).

Comment: OK I found this. But I cannot figure out how to get all layers (point layers)  inside the box. I changed the pic in my question box.

Comment: If the layers are in a map already you can loop through the layers in the layer panel and add the layer name text to the widget.  I would recommend first learning how to add any text to the widget and then how to get all layer names in a map.  If you have a specific question about coding you will need to post what you've tried in your question and note where you are stuck before others can assist.

Comment: The layers I want to select are already given in QGis. I have to open them manually. These layers should be selectable in the multi selection box.