# QtDesigner/QGIS 3: Which widget to use for multiple selections in ValueRelation?

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-plugins, pyqgis-3, qt-designer

I created a field of type ValueRelation allowing multiple selections in PyQGIS. Everything works as it should in the attribute table (see [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/239348/choosing-multiple-options-from-qgis-check-box-or-value-map-for-feature-attribute) for example). Now I'm trying to create a custom .ui in QtDesigner. And I can't figure out which widget to use for my field to work properly with the .ui. If I use a listView/listWidget, nothing shows in the list. If I use a comboBox, my list of values shows in the comboBox, but I can't select more than one value (and if I select multiple values directly in the attribute table, then none of them is selected in the comboBox). What is the appropriate QtDesigner Widget to use for multiple selections ValueRelations ?

In case this helps, here's the code I use to populate the list (and that works and poulates the list with the comboBox, but not with the listView/listWidget) :

```
    layer_ref_milieux=QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('REF_grds_types_milieux')[0].id()
    type_grds_types = 'ValueRelation'
    config_grds_types  = {'AllowMulti': True,
    'AllowNull': True,
    'FilterExpression': '',
    'Key': 'grd_type_short',
    'Layer': layer_ref_milieux,
    'LayerName': 'REF_grds_types_milieux',
    'LayerSource': 'dbname=' + bdd + ' host=' + host + ' port=' + port + ' user=' + user + ' key=\'id\' checkPrimaryKeyUnicity=\'1\' table="ref"."grds_types_milieux" (geom) sql=',
    'NofColumns': 1,
    'OrderByValue': True,
    'UseCompleter': False,
    'Value': 'grd_type'}
    grds_types_widget_setup = QgsEditorWidgetSetup(type_grds_types,config_grds_types)
    layer.setEditorWidgetSetup(grds_types_index, grds_types_widget_setup)
```

Comment: Are you talking about htis one [How to create “multiple layer selection” with Qt designer?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/212109/how-to-create-multiple-layer-selection-with-qt-designer)?

Comment: Yes, this is indeed one of the widgets I tried. And I did check the "MultiSelection" selection mode, as well as the "ImH Multiline" Input Method Hint. But nothing shows in the widget in QGIS.

Comment: Thx, needed the 'AllowMulti': True info, shame that the documentation is lacking here so much...